# Racket - How to implement filter using map, apply and append only

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

In functional programming,

How to implement filter using map, apply and append only (Without using other higher-order functions, recursions, nor mutations) ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
(define (filter ? lst)
  (apply append (map (λ (x) (if (? x) (list x) '())) lst)))
```

Comment: Did you mean `(if (? x) ...)`?